# handle large data set in R

Tags: r, distance, large-data

I  have   two large data sets , first data set is numeric , contains 60759 objects and 15 features the he second one is categorical contains 60759 objects and 9 features  ,I am trying to calculate Euclidean  distance   for numerical data set    and simple matching for categorical data set.  but i  could not  calculate them because of the size of data.

does any one has idea how can we handle large data in R

Comment: Please reformulate your question -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: At a glance, 60k+ rows / <20 columns doesn't seem large. How are your calculations done? Perhaps there are ways to make the code more efficient.

Comment: Have you tried the fread() function in the data.table package to read large data file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft R Open with RevoScaleR library. 
RevoScaleR library is designed to handle large amount of data by breaking into smaller chunks.

Look up here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r/concept-what-is-revoscaler
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-client/what-is-microsoft-r-client

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `paralleldDist` package C++ and multithread
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/parallelDist/parallelDist.pdf

```
parDist(x, method = "euclidean")
```